# R 2.14 byte compilation - how much performance increase

Tags: r, compilation, byte

I saw that the latest R version supports byte compilation. What is the performance gain I can expect? And are specific tasks more positively impacted that others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between a one- and five-fold increase:

http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/speed-tests-for-r-%E2%80%94-and-a-look-at-the-compiler/

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/04/12/

Comment: Do you mean between a one-fold and five-fold increase? Surely a zero-fold increase means the code stops running.

Comment: @Spaceman Yeah, looks right to me also.  What are you talking about? :-)

Answer (score 9):

It is a good question:

- The byte compiler appeared with 2.13.0 in April, and some of us run tests then (with thanks to gsk3 for the links).
- I tend to look more at what [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) can do for us, but I now always include 'uncompiled R' and 'byte compiled R' as baselines.
- I fairly often see gains by a factor of two (eg the [varSims example](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/04/23#rcpp_for_varsims)) but also essentially no gains at all (the [fibonacci](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/09/08#rcpp_for_recursion) example which is of course somewhat extreme).

We could do with more data.  When we had the precursor byte compile in the [Ra](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/ra/) engine by Stephen Milborrow (which I had packaged up for Debian too), it was often said that both algebraic expression and loops benefited. I don't know of a clear rule for the byte compiler by Luke Tierney now in R---but it generally *never seems to hurt* so it may be worthwhile to get into the habit of turning it on.

Comment: I think it is turned on by default in the binary versions, at least I am seeing new functions show up with what I think are compiler generated attributes.  Is that right?

Comment: IIRC the plan was to have 'base R' be byte-compiled for R 2.14.0. The News file may have more.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yes, I compiled from source (so easy on Ubuntu!) and this was the default.

Comment: @XuWang 'so easy by default' and yet so useless. I don't it---I upload to Debian, and get updated Ubuntu binaries thanks to Michael's work the next day. With the identical configuration as the Debian builds. YMMV, but you are likely to have a *less featureful* installation.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Interesting. I do it more to learn rather than for performance purposes I guess. I've been using your (and Michael's I guess) builds for a long time and I find them to be great. But I would like to learn about the configure options and also I might want to experiment with the R source code. But of course I could do that in an isolated, experimental folder and keep your + Michael's binary as the main install. hmm I'll think about that. Thanks!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - can you elaborate? I compiled from source and the only missing thing I notice are the graphical menus, which I don't really miss.

Comment: @XuWang: That's the right idea. You can even take our package sources and just build a local package from it (just increment the version in debian/changelog). That way you experiement to your hearts content yet revert if something is amiss.